# How to write if exist statement block to check if Powershell Modules are already installed using array of names

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, foreach, module

Update: Final Working Script per retryW's accepted solution. It was the easiest way to achieve what I was overall trying to do.

```
##########################
### INSTALL PS MODULES ###
##########################
Function inmod { Clear-Host

$modulesArray = @(
  "Convert",
  "Get-UserProfile",
  "Get-WindowsVersion",
  "PoshInternals",
  "PSConsoleTheme",
  "PSSpeedTest",
  "UpdateOS",
  "WindowsPSModulePath",
  "WindowsConsoleFonts",
  "xFailOverCluster"
)

ForEach($mod in $modulesArray) {
    If(Get-Module -ListAvailable $mod) {
        Continue; CLS
    } Else {
        Write-Host "Installing '$mod'"
        Install-Module $mod -Force -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
    }
  }
}

#############################
### UN-INSTALL PS MODULES ###
#############################
Function unmod { Clear-Host

$modulesArray = @(
  "Convert",
  "Get-UserProfile",
  "Get-WindowsVersion",
  "PSConsoleTheme",
  "PSSpeedTest",
  "WindowsPSModulePath",
  "WindowsConsoleFonts",
  "xFailOverCluster"
)

ForEach($mod in $modulesArray) {
    If(Get-Module -ListAvailable $mod) {
        Continue; CLS
    } Else {
        Write-Host "Un-Installing '$mod'"
        Uninstall-Module $mod
    }
  }
}

#################################
### UN-INSTALL ALL PS MODULES ###
#################################
Function unmodall { Clear-Host

ForEach($mods in (Get-Module -ListAvailable *).Name | Get-Unique) {
   Write-Host "Un-Installing '$mod'"
   Uninstall-Module $mod
  }
}

#########################
### UPDATE PS MODULES ###
#########################
Function upmod { Clear-Host

$modulesArray = @(
  "Convert",
  "Get-UserProfile",
  "Get-WindowsVersion",
  "PoshInternals",
  "PSConsoleTheme",
  "PSSpeedTest",
  "UpdateOS",
  "WindowsPSModulePath",
  "WindowsConsoleFonts",
  "xFailOverCluster"
)

ForEach($mod in $modulesArray) {
    If(Get-Module -ListAvailable $mod) {
        Continue; CLS
    } Else {
        Write-Host "Updating '$mod'"
        Update-Module $mod -Force
    }
  }
}
```

Old Update: In response to Lee_Dailey

I have progressed my script to the below point using some of his points/suggestions.

I think however I am having new issues even though I am finding matches this time.

`If ($_ -match $item)` seems to be working fine.

`If ($_ -notmatch $item)` seems to not be working.

I think I know why but I'm not completely sure. It may be matching every match that is found with `ForEach ($item in (Get-Module -ListAvailable *).Name | Get-Unique)` and that is somehow causing an issue??

Thanks for the help so far... it has helped me progress a lot!

```
Function imods {
Write-Host; CLS

$AddModulesArray = @(
"Convert",
"Get-UserProfile",
"Get-WindowsVersion",
"PoshInternals",
"PSConsoleTheme",
"PSSpeedTest",
"UpdateOS",
"WindowsPSModulePath",
"WindowsConsoleFonts",
"xFailOverCluster"
)

ForEach ($item in (Get-Module -ListAvailable *).Name | Get-Unique) {
$_ = $item
$AddModulesArray | ForEach-Object {
If ($_ -notmatch $item) {
  Write-Host
  Write-Host Installing $_
  Install-Module -Name $_
  Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
  }
Else {
If ($_ -match $item) {
  Write-Host
  Write-Host $_ Already Exists
  Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
    }
   }
 }
}
}
```

Additionally, I know that it is not considered good practice to break up lines using the ` but I find it easier to read this way.

Comment: you are using `foreach` - the loop constrict - as if it was the `ForEach-Object` pipeline construct. that won't work. [*grin*] for instance, where is the `$_` coming from in `If ($item -eq $_)`?

Comment: also, your `$AddModulesArray` has no need for the backticks. that is a valid array definition without them ... and you can leave off the commas, too! [*grin*]

Comment: also also, note that you have no delimiter or `{}` after the `)` in the following `ForEach ($item in $AddModulesArray)Get-Module`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify this greatly and speed it up by only looping through the list of modules you want installed, rather all modules.

```bsh
function imods {
    # Clear screen
    Clear-Host

    # Modules we need
    $modulesArray = @(
        "Convert",
        "Get-UserProfile",
        "Get-WindowsVersion",
        "PoshInternals",
        "PSConsoleTheme",
        "PSSpeedTest",
        "UpdateOS",
        "WindowsPSModulePath",
        "WindowsConsoleFonts",
        "xFailOverCluster"
    )

    # Rather than looking through both arrays, just loop through the ones we care about
    foreach($mod in $modulesArray) {
        if(Get-Module -ListAvailable $mod) {
            # Module exists
            Write-Host "Module '$mod' is already installed"
        } else {
            # Module does not exist, install it
            Write-Host "Installing '$mod'"
            Install-Module $mod
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good advice and working script example. I updated my original post with my current working script modeled from your answer. Thanks again!